# Angular order Object by properties

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an angular app which consumes `json` from an API endpoint. The `json` data arrives like so:

**tasks:**

```
$scope.tasks = [ {id:23, title:'foo'}, {id:448, title:'bar'} ]
```

But for the sake of easily accessing the data within angular I map th objects so that I get something like:

```
$scope.tasks = { 23:{id: 23, title:'foo'}, 448:{id:23, title:'foo'} }
```

This allows me to pull out `task` instances and modify task instances using their `id` only.

The consequence of this that I have lost the easy `orderBy` methods of Angular, though `ng-repeat` continues to function as expected.

So, my question is, if I want to now order my list by `title` or `-title`, how can this be achieved? Is there anything in Angular to accomplish this or should I roll my own filter?

**EDIT**

so in my template I want to do this:

```
<div ng-repeat="task in tasks | orderBy:'-title'">
    <span>{{ task.title }}</span>
</div>
```

So the `orderBy` filter works if the code is in the first format but doesn't work if the code is mapped as in the second format.

Comment: please post code or Fiddle with your issue. It will help us alot

Comment: I have added the template code which is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just write a method to pull out a task based on a given ID, rather than re-format the response from the API and write your own repeater directives?

```
function getTask(id) {
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.tasks.length; i++) {
        if ($scope.tasks[i].id == id)
            return $scope.tasks[i];
     }
}
```

The above task will still be binded to that `$scope.tasks` array, so any property changes you make should be reflected in the view.

Comment: Hmm. I took the decision to map the objects so as the object can be updated, deleted easily. I wanted to avoid having to iterate through an array of objects every time this occurred.

Comment: @DarwinTech -- I see your point there, but the iteration will have to occur regardless if you're going to be rolling your own filters and orders

Comment: But, this thread may help ya out if for sorting objects: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1286

Comment: Yeah, after some consideration I decided to take your advice and scrap the object mapping. So, yay! I have `orderBy` back! If you would like to provide an answer I can accept it, though it may obfuscate the OP.